# Rails: resource management via tabs/ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Traditionally, a resource's index displays all of its objects, which you click to be taken to their respective show (or edit, delete, etc) methods.  Instead, our interface is more iPad-like (or Lion's new [Mail](http://www.techcavern.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/lion-mail.jpg) app), in the sense that the index displays all of its objects as tabs on the left, with a large content area on the right.  Clicking an object fills the right content area with that object's show partial.

It seems to me that this will just require changing the show (and edit, etc) `link_to`'s to `:remote => true` which will invoke `show.js.erb` which replaces the right-hand content with the new show partial.

```
// show.js.erb 
$('#right').html(' <%= render :partial => "show" %> ');
```

Assuming that is the best way (?), it means a `***.js.erb` file is needed for nearly every controller action of every resource that we want to have this behavior.  Anyway to DRY that up?

Answer (score 0):

$("#right").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("show")) %>");

I recommend this Right way on rails-3.

Comment: Thanks, Andy.  Didn't think I needed to add escape_javascript, as it's just example code, and not really critical to the question.